# PHP scripts executing multiple times from a single HTTP request

Tags: php

So Http uses **TCPIP** and that has automatic retries. I saw some behavior where a message appears to have hit the server 3 times at the same time. I am wondering if during poor connections, will the TCPIP retry trigger extra PHP calls?

If this is the case, how does one avoid duplicating effort? I have safeguards upon repeating the same transaction, but if they arrive at the exact same instant its much harder to do that.

Comment: Please provide your data source linking the extra calls and etc.

Comment: I don't now if this help or if that is your case, but as far as i now , tcp/ip is trasparent to request because is a protocol layer and it's more deeper ..  i saw this behaviors specially  when you're doing Ajax requests and the events are not well coded...

Answer (score 2):

No, TCP retransmission won't duplicate the requests. TCP retransmission occurs within the context of a single connection, it doesn't create multiple connections. And the retransmitted segments have the same sequence numbers as the original segments; if the server receives both of them (i.e. the lost segment was the acknowledgement), it can tell that the second one is a duplicate and it will ignore it automatically.